# Remote Mysql DB not able to connect by docker-compose spring boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am containerize the spring-boot application in which the DB is Mysql-8.

The DB is hosted on different machine.

We wanted to connect it from container based service but wont be able to connect it.

The machine's IP is configured in the Mysql to allow connectivity.

Is there any setting required on docker side to allow communication?  OR  any changes required on Mysql side?

Same thing is working when I am running the service from my machine to connect to DB.

Any inputs, pointers really appreciated.

The configuration and steps involved are:

1.The pom.xml changes to create image of spring-boot service.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>abc/uvw-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

2. To build the image from above changes.

> spring-boot:build-image

3. jdbc.properties file. **wsnw-pc3** is the machine in network where DB is hosted.

> ```
> jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
> jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://wsnw-pc3:3306/xxxx?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
> jdbc.username=<username>
> jdbc.password=<password>
> ```

4. Docker compose file changes

> ```
> version: '3.8'
>
> services:
>   myservice:
>     image: abc/uvw-myservice:1.0
>     deploy:
>       resources:
>         limits:
>           memory: 700m
>     ports:
>       - "8080:8080"
> ```

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: Are you able to connect to the remote MySQL database from your host environment (instead of a Docker one)?

Comment: Yes, I am @jeroen

Comment: add your spring application docker to host. --network=host in docker run or docker network connect host <containerId>

Comment: @Atul Is it possible to post the docker commands or docker-compose configuration that you use locally in order to connect the container to the remote database?

Comment: @Jeroen van der Laan added required information. Let me know anything required.

Comment: Did you grant privileges to `'username'@'localhost'`, or to `'username'@'%'`?

Comment: Yes .... I have given the privileges what it required.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the answer? Scenario: Docker compose with spring and angular, but I want database outside, as I want to test like CloudSQL scenario - So mysql is running in a  different container. Cant use localhost in my spring database url

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I'm trying to connect to a DB that is run on the host machine with a containerized Spring Boot app.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    network_mode: host # add this line
...
```